# How to move a div next to other divs with arrow keys (and make enter click a link)

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on redoing my homepage for my Web Design class. I want to recreate the style of the apple II for the project, although I do not want to have the titles of the projects as simply links, as I believe the Apple II did not even have a mouse.

My main plan is to recreate the way that Five Nights at Freddy's 3 did the menu, namely, moving a cursor over the various options and pressing enter to go through that link. I have searched far and wide on the internet, and, since the class mostly goes over HTML and CSS, I don't have much skill in terms of Javascript, meaning I don't really have any idea how to do this at all.

Here is my code

```
  <div class="crt">
  <div class="title">
  <h1> DIRECTORIES </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="projects">
  <br>
  <a href="Alien.html"> <h1 class="directory"> ] NOUN</h1> </a> <div class="cursor">  </div>
  <br>
  <a href="Convince.html"> <h1 class="directory"> ] CONVINCE</h1> </a>
  <br>
  <a href="Restaurant.html"> <h1 class="directory"> ] RESTAURANT</h1> </a>
  <br>
  <a href="Event/Event.html"> <h1 class="directory"> ] EVENT </h1> </a>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I have put the div ".cursor" next to the first link option for now, but I am unsure how, if I even can, move it down next to the one for the "convince" project or further, as well as back up.

Comment: Use CSS pseudo classes :hover :focus :focus-visible etc. to style how your links look when the user interacts with them, by default enter will follow a link that is currently selected

Comment: But how could I make it so that the div is focused with the .cursor div next to it?

Comment: Wrap the cursor div to inside of the link

Comment: Or put the cursor div before the link, and use the adjacent sibling selector `+`

Comment: I was trying your second method and I can't seem to get it to work, I put the cursor before the text and it just remains the same and pushes the text down a row (nevermind I fixed that but it still doesn't change the text) (odd because I have both ".directory" and ".cursor" set as "display: inline-block") and doesn't apply any of the changes I write out.

Comment: I still don't know why you have to use a div, ditch the div or put it inside the link

Comment: I want to use the div so that I can make it look like how they did the old cursor for the Apple II. But if I didn't do a div what would I use as the cursor element?

Comment: I still can't get the adjacent sibling selector to work. I'm not sure what I'm even doing wrong though since I have "div + h1" as the selector yet it's not working.

Comment: In the markup above it looks like your h1 is inside of the a element and therefore it isn't a sibling of the div